# Selecionar campo não vazio

Tags: php, sql

tabela demo

```
 id  imagem       flash       codigo
 1   fda.jpg
 2             asdfasd.sfw
 3                           adsense
```

existe alguma forma de SELECIONAR apenas o não vazio? se sim qual a melhor forma no PHP ou SQL?

```
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicidade ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";

         if flash,image = "" echo codgio

         if codigo,image = "" echo flash
```

é por ai ou tem algum metodo mais proprio?

Comment: Os valores vazios são strings vazias ou `NULL`?

Comment: São strings Vazias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a expressão [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) no select, por exemplo:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN imagem != '' THEN imagem
    WHEN flash != '' THEN flash
    WHEN codigo != '' THEN codigo
    ELSE NULL
  END AS val
FROM publicidade
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

E em php, com o resultado dessa query você pode usar:

```
echo $row['val'];
```

Comment: realmente funcionou porem agora que vi aqui tem que ser via php mesmo pois os codigos de chamadas são diferentes para cada tipo vou ver se o case do php funciona da mesma forma

Comment: Tente usar uma modelagem melhor no banco de dados. O correto seria ter uma coluna do tipo do valor, é não uma coluna para cada tipo. Por exemplo, `tipo_publicidade => "imagem"`, `valor_publicidade => "fda.jpg"`. Dessa forma você precisaria apenas checar o tipo do valor, nem precisaria dessa consulta que escrevi como resposta. Se quiser eu te explico melhor em outro lugar.